# True or false: $H \cap K= 1$, $H$ centralizes $K \implies K=1$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and let $H$,$K$ be its subgroups such that $H \cap K=1$. *From the hypothesis $H$ centralizes $K$, is it correct to conclude that $K=1$?*

I'm reasoning as follows: if $H$ centralizes $K$, we have $H \leq C_G(K) \leq N_G(K)$, so $K \trianglelefteq H$. In particular, $K \leq H$, therefore $H \cap K= K$. Since $H \cap K=1$, we have $K=1$.

Is my thought correct? Thanks for the tips

Comment: $H\le N_G(K)$ does not imply $K\trianglelefteq H$ if $K$ isn't a subgroup of $H$ to begin with. Your hypotheses are consistent with any direct product $H\times K$, for example.

Answer (score 2):

$H\le N_G(K)$ doesn't necessarily imply that $K\le H$, let alone $K\trianglelefteq H$.

A counter-example to what you mentionned is a direct product $H\times K$; each factor in a direct product centralizes the other factor.

On the other hand, there are subgroups called [malnormal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malnormal_subgroup). In your example, if $K$ is assumed to be malnormal, then it follows indeed that $K$ is trivial.